# Suffix for URL of Tenants in Multi Tenancy in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, url, multi-tenancy

I have a Multi-Tenant SP 2013 on-premise farm. We have one web application with multiple tenants. Since we use Host Named Site Collections for Multi-Tenancy, we give a new host name for every tenant. We follow a naming convention `HTTP://{TenantName}.{ClientName}.{Suffix}` for every tenant URL's root site collection.

I have a question related to the suffix. We want to use the short name for the environment as the suffix. For example, for the development environment, it should be something like "dev", for staging it should be something like "stg", for QA, it should be something like "qa" and so on. But is this correct / feasible?

Also, is there any restriction that a single web application can support only a single suffix? Please help with your inputs / suggestions.